# A* Pathfinding off Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, path, path-finding

I have a game character that I am animating around the screen. 
For very specific reasons this character must be inside a DIV (off-canvas).

I'm drawing a black and white image to a canvas and looping the pixel data to define the character's walkable areas. Works great.

Now need to setup pathfinding. 
I've read a ton of articles about using the A* algorithm and it seems to make perfect sense... when you're moving the character inside a game loop.

So, how would I be able to pass my path movement information to my character (DIV) when they're not being drawn within a canvas loop? 
Is this possible, or are there any known workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: So is your question "how do you implement pathfinding without a central loop"? Maybe its just cause I don't know much about the Canvas element but how do you want to have a progression over time without some sort of looping mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your assumption seems to be that you have to move your character to complete the A* algorithm. You don't have to move your actual character. Basically, you create a "simulation" of your character and the board and move that.

**1-**

create a representation of your walkable area in code. Sounds like you've pretty much done this, but instead of displaying it, store it in an array or something; some way that makes sense to you (a 2D array?).

**2-**

Instead of drawing and moving your actual character, in the code, run through the A* algorithm. The idea here is to solve the problem and know the pathfinding solution before your character starts moving. There are a couple of ways to do this depending on how A* is implemented but after it runs, you want to have generated a representation of the path you want to take (starting from (0,0), go to (0,1), go to (1,1), etc).

**3-**

Pass that path information to your character. Now it has a step by step plan on how to get to the end before its even started.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks so much for your response. I had gotten to the second step and the problem is "go to 0,0 go to 1,1" as you explained. It looks like I'll have to rewrite my character walking function to allow for this. This gives me a good idea of how to approach it. Thanks! :D